# What is the difference between the three types of logarithms?

Tags: complex-analysis, notation, logarithms

In complex analysis I came across three types of logarithms
 namely $\ln$, $\log$ and $\text{Log}$. What is the difference between the three?

Comment: Doesn't the text where you found those notations explain their meaning?

Comment: $\log_ba$ is the logarithm of $a$, base $b$. When no $b$ is specified, $b=e$, This is the natural logarithm. Another way of denoting the natural logarithm is $\ln n$

Comment: Typically a graduate math text on complex analysis will use $\log$ to refer to the natural logarithm.  In computer/numerical analysis contexts it may be more common to use $\ln$ for the natural logarithm and to use a subscript on $\log$ or $\operatorname{Log}$ to distinguish logarithms to other bases (such as two or ten).  Your text should indicate the definitions if multiple notations are used.

Comment: I would think $\ln$ and $\log$ are the same and that $\operatorname{Log}$ refers to the principal logarithm as listed here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm under "Definition of Principal Value".

Comment: The book from which I have read them has not explained them fully.

Comment: It is a perfectly reasonable question.

Comment: If the book distinguishes ln front log without a base then log without a base is probably 20 (and will probably almost never be used).  I imagine in the book it will become very clear.  There's also a somewhat little used lg which means log base 2.

Comment: @fleablood: By "20" do you mean "10"?

Comment: Yes, I meant 10.  I also meant "from" and not "front".

Comment: Their bases, and there is therefore an infinite number of types. Three in common use: *e*, 10, and 2.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I thing if $z=re^{i\theta}$ then
$\log z=\ln r+i\theta$. Now if in the arguement $\theta ,n=1$ then "$\log$" becomes "Log". Also "$\ln$" is generally used with real part of complex number as per the notations used by C.V.Chirchill

Comment: What does "in the arguement $\theta, n = 1$" mean?

Comment: There may be a language problem in narrating the answer but that doesnt mean the answer is wrong.Actually the argument $\theta$ satisfies $logre^{i\theta}=lnr+i\theta$ so does $2n\pi+\theta$

Comment: Yeah, I don't know why people downvoted your answer, it is kind of unfair.

Comment: There seems to be no reference as to what this "$n$" thing is in the answer. It's apparently a part of the argument, so…what does that mean? Your comment makes up for what lacks in the answer though, namely, you explain why we should bother about any $n$. Honestly, upon first reading the answer, I thought you meant that the $n$ in "$ln$" should be 1, which is clearly wrong. Nowhere in either the question or in your answer is it explained that an $n$ variable even exists, so I assume that is where the downvote came from. "language problem", not so much, rather an "explain yourself" one…

Comment: Answer + comment is good though, +1.

Comment: I have a BS in Mathenatics and I do not understand this answer at all. Am I the only one? I think it would help a lot if proper markup were used for the mathematics in this answer.

Comment: First question, does $r=re^{i\theta}$ mean that either $r=0$ or $e^{i\theta}=1$ as it would seem? If no why not, if yes, why not say this explicitly?

Comment: ok I accept that I have not been able to give a proper explaination....

Answer (score 28):

- ***ln*** is **always** a natural logarithm (of base $e$).
- ***log*** if it has a base like $\log_5x$ then the base is the specified one, otherwise it is either base $e$ or base $10$. It depends on people. Some people (mostly high school people) use logarithms without a base as base $10$ and other people as base $e$. It is most often used as a natural logarithm though but you have to watch out. **If you see a ln button on a calculator, then log without base is guaranteed to be base 10 on the same calculator.**

*(Edit: As @ClementC. pointed out, in computer science, $log$ without a base most often means a binary logarithm.)*

- ***Log*** stands for complex logarithm in its **principal branch**. The principal branch has its imaginary part in the interval $(−π,π]$. (Basically it's the inverse of the complex exponential function with its imaginary part in that interval.)

Comment: In mathematics $\log$ tends to always mean the natural log.

Comment: Not always, some people like to put it as base 10 unfortunately... so you have to watch out.

Comment: $\text{Log}$ is often defined as the [*principal branch*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm#Definition_of_principal_value) of the complex logarithm.

Comment: In computer science, more often than not $\log$ is used for base $2$. (*Sometimes*, it is specified in the "preliminaries" section of the paper.)

Comment: @ClementC. yeah, now I edited the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Concise!  High school (pre university) log nearly always means 10.  In college math log nearly always means the natural log in base e (because 10 is meaningless and arbitrary).  I imagine in the physical sciences log without a base may mean 10 as that's useful for metric system but that's a guess.

Comment: In physics, especially high energy $\log$ is used to mean base $e$

Comment: Yeah, it is most often used as base $e$.

Comment: Also, until around the 1970s, *log* usually designed the decimal log, simply because it was ubiquitous in numerical computations "by hand", with a table of logarithms or a slide rule. This use is really what made the decimal log popular in the first place, I guess.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I think so too.

Comment: @ClementC. Alternative notations for $\log_2 x$ or [binary logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_logarithm) include $\lg x$, $\operatorname{ld} x$, and $\operatorname{lb} x$.

Comment: MSExcel and many calculators use $\log$ to mean $\log_{10}$

Comment: @MSExcel that's a good point, I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: @GregBacon $\lg x$ has been used exclusively as the decimal logarithm for at least the last hundred years. Well, in some countries.

Comment: Also, in computer science $\log$ often means just "any logarithm" - the base doesn't matter as logarithms are all equal up to a constant factor.

Comment: In economics, also, log tends to always mean the natural log.

Comment: This is the first I'm hearing of "log" implying base $e$, even at the college level, but I never got straight As (or perfect scores) so maybe I got this wrong every time in my university courses and it just didn't come up often enough for me to realize it or fail any tests. When I think of the last two years of my BS, I don't recall using any kind of logarithm. Once is was done with differential equations it rarely to never came up. In my freshmen calculus courses at university, I'm pretty sure we were taking "log" to mean base $10$ just like in high school.

Comment: I did have more than one professor who would **say** "log" while they **wrote** "ln" on the board, so in *speech* I would agree that most people say "log" to mean base $e$ rather then saying the more awkward "ell en".

Comment: I think the only rule is that $\log$ means the kind of logarithm the author prefers. So that is the natural logarithm for mathematicians, logarithm base (decimal) 10 at high school and for engineers, and log base 2 (that's binary 10) for computer scientists. The explanation is simple, $\log$ is shorter to write than $\ln$ or $\lg$ ;-) Besides it avoids the question of whether the 'n' in $\ln$ means "natural" or "Neperian" (adjective of Napier).

Comment: In physics, it depends... You ought to be able to tell from context. It's pretty common to see $\ln x$, which relegates $\log x$ to base 10. This makes sense if your field has, say, industry applications that use conventions like the dB to describe systems. But, you should anticipate that $\log x$ could refer to base $e$.

Answer (score 6):

These are notations, sometimes ambiguous, to denote potentially different types of logarithms, which depend on the language of origin (Russian, German, French), see for instance [where $\lg$ is used](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Lg.html), including number theory, since sometimes $\log_2 x $ denotes the iterated logarithm: $\log{\log{ x }}$.

Notation $\ln x$ (almost) unambiguously denotes the [natural logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm) $\log_e x$  (latin: *logarithmus naturalis*), or logarithm in base $e$. In French, I used to believe the "n" stood for "népérien", from Neper or Napier.

The notation $\log x$ should be the adopted notation for the natural logarithm, and it is so in mathematics. However, it often represents the "most natural" depending on the field: I learned it as the base-$10$ logarithm ($\log_{10} x$) at school, and it is often used this way in engineering (for instance in the definition of [decibels](http://www.animations.physics.unsw.edu.au/jw/dB.htm)): [image]
And it may also represent a base-$2$ logarithm ([binary logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_logarithm)) in binary calculus. The latter is sometimes denoted [lg, ld (logarithmus dualis), or lb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_logarithm#Notation).

$\operatorname{Log} x$ normally is  the principal value for a complex number, with imaginary part in the interval $(-\pi,\pi]$. But, while I learned at school $\log x$ for $\log_{10} x$, $\operatorname{Log} x$ was used (wrongly) to denote the natural logarithm. Such notations can be found for instance in [Calcul differentiel et integral. Tome 1](http://fr.scribd.com/doc/26412181/Calcul-Differentiel-Et-Integral-Tome1-N-Piskounov-Mir), 1998, N. Piskounov, page 58 sq.

The [History of logarithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_logarithms) wikipedia page is worth reading, if only to learn the origin of the name (a number indicating a ratio: *logos*, proportion, and *arithmos*, number), and John Napier's book: Mirifici Logarithmorum Canonis Descriptio (Description of the Wonderful Rule of Logarithms).